# await causing web socket connections to close

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, websocket, async-await

I need to establish multiple web socket connections that will forever receive updates unless they quit through some case. I need to have these socket connections be awaited since this loop of polling for update events is limiting the number of threads that can be run at once thus limiting the number of connections I can open.

I attempted to solve this problem by using a semaphore as a way to detect events (the events are being observed through a IObserver interface)

```
static SemaphoreSlim send = new SemaphoreSlim(0,1);
static object newUpdate;
static numberOfClients = 0;
```

and the loop to poll and possibly receive updates or terminate

```
while(true)
{
   await send.WaitAsync() //wait the thread so others can start 
   //do some things with the updated valu and send data or possibly quit
}
```

and in the OnNext implementation that detects events

```
public void OnNext(object value)
{
   newUpdate = value;
   for (int i = 0; i < numberOfClients; i++)
   {
      send.Release();
      Thread.Sleep(100);
   }
}
```

and the client implementation:

```
    do
    {
        try
        {
           WebSocketReceiveResult result = await websocket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, CancellationToken.None);

            byte[] receivedData = new byte[result.Count];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer.Array, 0, receivedData, 0, result.Count);
            if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Text)
            {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nReceived message: " + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(receivedData));
            }
        }
        catch (WebSocketException e)
        {
            if (websocket.State == WebSocketState.Aborted)
            {
                break;
            }
            continue;
    }

        if (result.EndOfMessage)
        {
           break;
        }
    }
    while (websocket.State == WebSocketState.Open);
```

When I execute this it seems that the line:

```
await send.WaitAsync()
```

immediately makes the client code crash when it tries to call await .ReceiveAsync() and cries:

```
 "Unable to read data from transport connection. An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host".
```

Any ideas how I can accomplish something like this? This is using OWIN WebSocket Extension.

Comment: Did you try to have a simple client-server application working before doing anything more complicated? Basically, just a client that connects to the server, sends one message to the server and then receives a response from the server.

Comment: Yes it works for any number of clients up to 32. After 32 try and receive updates threads stop being scheduled (probably a constraint on the processing power) which is why we are trying to yield a threads execution before trying to check for a update

Comment: Edit - Sorry it works if you don't use the await to try and yield a threads execution. But if we don't yield a threads execution in some way then we have the problem I mentioned above

Comment: I don't follow exactly what is your initial goal. When you say "updates", what do you mean exactly? What I understand is that you have multiple clients that connect to a server through a websocket and you need to exchange messages between the clients and the server. Then, from what you say, is that you stop receiving messages on the server if you have more than 32 clients connected at the same time. Am I right?  How many messages are exchanged per seconds? Are your running the server on a machine with limited resources (CPU, ...)?

Comment: Imagine the await send.WaitAsyc() line was instead send.Wait(). I am seeing a maximum amount of 32 clients being able to enter that while loop and be blocked by the semaphore. It seems that any client number that tries to establish a connection that is greater than 32 the threads are not being scheduled to run any further after 32 threads get stuck in this while() loop.

This has nothing to do with sending data. I cannot even have 32 clients connect and enter the while loop to be blocked by the semaphore. This is why we wanted to use await and WaitAync to yield the thread.

Comment: But if we attempt only to establish 1 client web socket connection and the thread executes await send.WaitAsync() then immediately on the client side it is treating it like we are focibly closing the connection.

Comment: It's really hard to see what is the problem without seeing the code of the server. If you are using async/await on the server, I am not sure why you need one thread per client. I would suggest to use a tool like [.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/) to write and share the smallest code sample possible to display the problem. The client side and the server side. This way, we would be able to reproduce your problem and try to help you.